# Celery is connecting to amqp://guest**@localhost instead of Redis. Heroku deploy

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery

I have read simillar topics and done everything there was being suggested, but the problem remains.

I am deploying my app to Heroku. Locally everything was working fine, but during deploy after specyfying every setting I could think off to specify the celery worker sends following error:

> :22:50.722826+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2018-10-21 18:22:50,722: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.

I tried switching from CloudAMQP to Redis. And the problem remains.

Here are my config files:

**Django's settings.py:**

```
try: 
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ['REDIS_URL']
except KeyError: 
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://admin:admin@localhost:5672/admin_host'

try:
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ['REDIS_URL']
except KeyError:
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://admin:admin@localhost:5672/admin_host'


CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from . import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'file_upload.settings')

app = Celery('file_upload', broker_pool_limit=1)

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**__init__.py from the package containig celery.py and settings.py:**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

and the `os.environ['REDIS_URL']` does return a url, I checked it.

anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of days fighting with this thing, and just after posting this I answered myself. Somebody may find this useful.

In my case the key for solving this was that I hardcoded redis URL in `celery.py` and passed it as argument while creating celery app object:

```
app = Celery('file_upload', broker_pool_limit=1, broker=redis_url,
             result_backend=redis_url)
```

Comment: Thanks for leaving this question and answer here on Stackoverflow! I have been working on this for days. Very useful!

Answer (score 2):

In order to solve this, I think what needs to be done is change the CELERY_BROKER_URL var to BROKER_URL. It should only be CELERY_BROKER_URL if you give it the namespace CELERY when you're fetching the config from the object.
Change from:

```
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
```

To:

```
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```

Answer (score 0):

In local/development environments, when we use kombu instead of ampq, celery broker url configuration it's set like:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'django://'  # for example
```

In your celery.py the call to the constructor for create the celery app must be set like this:

```
django_url = settings.CELERY_BROKER_URL
app = Celery('tone_insurance', broker=django_url, result_backend=django_url)
```

This is based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52918698/9491934)